# "java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Tags: java, database, connectivity

can't connect to my database. this give me an error message "java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

here is my code:

```
package youtubetest;
import java.sql.*;

public class YoutubeTest {

        private static final String USERNAME = "root";
        private static final String PASSWORD = "root";
        private static final String CONN_STRING = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/youtube";

        public static void main(String args []) {
            Connection conn = null;

            try {
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                System.out.println("Connected!");
            }catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: can you double check your credential ? and maybe your database name ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seems to be a problem in your code.
Have you tried to connect to the database manually to check if this user and password is correct?

If you are using Windows, see this:
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/connect-to-mysql-windows-command-line

Or Debian/Ubuntu:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-connect-to-my-mysql-database-server-using-command-line-and-php/

Comment: not yet tried to connect to database manually. I will try it out